# Laravel 6 escapando html blade template

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou exibindo notícias cadastradas no banco de dados usando laravel e template blade, so que o html esta sendo escapado, já tentei várias formas mas não consigo resolver.

Meu controller retornando resultado da consulta para o blade:

```
 return view('public.news', [ 'data' => $news[0] ]);
```

E no blade chamo dessa forma:

```
{{ data.text }}
```

Mas o html esta sendo escapado, o navegador não interpreta as tags, saindo dessa forma:

```
<div><p>A Caixa Econômica Federal disponibilizou na terça-feira (7) o site e o aplicativo por meio do qual informais, autônomos, desempregados e MEIs já podem solicitar o auxílio emergencial de R$ 600.</p><p class="content-text__container "> <strong>
```

Já tentei usar `{! data.text !}`, `{!! data.text !!}`, `{{ html_entity_decode(data.text) }}` ... e nada, o blade nem interpreta essas ações, imprime desse jeito mesmo no html, alguém  poderia me auxiliar a resolver?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver utilizando:

```
{% autoescape false %} {{ data.text }} {% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 2):

A flag `autoescape` ([aqui](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/autoescape.html)) é do template Twig e não do Blade. Por mais que o laravel deixe você usar os dois ao mesmo tempo, isso irá confundir outros desenvolvedores posteriormente [aqui](https://medium.com/@barryvdh/comparing-blade-and-twig-templates-in-laravel-187fde7fcac9).

Não sei ao certo qual versão do Laravel tu está utilizando mas as duas formas corretas seriam:

Para laravel 4 podes usar:

```php
{{ html_entity_decode($content) }}
```

Para laravel 5+ ([aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data)) podes usar:

```php
{!! $content !!}
```